# separate array numbers and save them in float

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point

I have an array which contains 12 numbers and I want to save this 12 numbers in 12 floats.generally how should I do this and save each one of them in one float?

```
array numbers = { a,b,c,....}
object1 = a;
object2 = b;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: tell us which type of numbers ur array contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... };
float f1 = (float) numbers[0];
float f2 = (float) numbers[1];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

float[] num_floats = new float[numbers.length];

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    num_floats[i] = (float) numbers[i];
}
```